# Python http request and loop over contents of JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to learn Python and have following problem:
I get an error while running this as it cannot see the `'name'` attribute in data.
It works when I grab one by one items from JSON. However when I want to do it in a loop it fails.
I assume my error is wrong request. That it cannot read JSON correctly and see attributes.

```
import requests
import json

def main():

    req = requests.get('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')

    print("HTTP Status Code: " + str(req.status_code))
    print(req.headers)
    json_obj = json.loads(req.content)

    for i in json_obj['name']:
        print(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: `for i in json_obj['name']` does not make sense (just check the response), try `for i in json_obj['results']`

Comment: for i in json_obj['name']:
{''}
KeyError: 'name'

Comment: in your json_obj you have only this keys: [u'count', u'next', u'results', u'previous'] so you can't search for name

Comment: It meant request is not correct because JSON file has 'name' attribute in it for each entry. Im just not getting JSON file correctly

Comment: Using 'results' as proposed by Soon worked somehow. It prints all the contents of JSON file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to access the `name` attribute of the `results` attribute in your `json_object` like this:

```
  for pokemon in json_obj['results']:
    print (pokemon['name'])
```

I was able to guess that you want to access the `results` keys because I have looked at the result of

```
json_obj.keys()
```

that is

```
dict_keys(['count', 'previous', 'results', 'next'])
```

Comment: yes. This worked! So the the 'results' is what i get while i query all JSON file and then i should mention attribute name of that 'result'... I've got the logic!

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Because all pokemons are saved in a list which is under keyword `results`, so you firstly need to get that list and then iterate over it.

```
for result in json_obj['results']:
print(result['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things: as soon mentioned, iterating through `json_obj['name']` doesn't really make sense - use `json_obj['results']` instead.

Also, you can use `req.json()` which is a method that comes with the `requests` library by default. That will turn the response into a dictionary which you can then iterate through as usual (`.iteritems()` or `.items()`, depending if you're using Python 2 or 3).